# QPainter ignores clipping inside paintEvent

Tags: qt, qwidget, clip, qpainter, qt4.8

I am trying to a draw text below a `QPushButton` (outside of the bounds of the button) whenever it gets focused. For this I have subclassed `QPushButton` and I am drawing text using `QPainter` drawText method inside overriden `paintEvent` method of `QPushButton`. Before drawing I am setting `QPainter::setClipping(false)` to enable text drawing out side button's bounds. But somehow `QPainter::setClipping(false)` is not working and the text is not getting drawn outside the button bounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The painter's paint engine itself implements clipping at a lower level, and the widget painter is not clipping by default. In other words: it's impossible to turn this clipping off. The following holds:

```
void Class::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev) {
  Parent::paintEvent(ev);
  QPainter p(this);
  Q_ASSERT(!p.hasClipping());
  // and now you do:
  p.setClipping(false); // this is a no-op!
}
```

A simple solution is to add a widget that draws the text as a sibling of the button, and locate it below the button. That widget can be a `QLabel`.

```
static const char kLabelSibling[] = "qq_labelSibling";
static const char kTrackedSibling[] = "qq_trackedSibling";

void setTextBelow(QWidget *widget, const QString &text) {
  Q_ASSERT(widget->parent);
  class Filter : QObject {
    static QLabel *getLabel(QObject *sibling) {
      return widget->property(kLabelSibling).value<QLabel*>();
    }
    static void updateLabel(QWidget *label) {
      auto *sibling = label->property(kTrackedSibling).value<QWidget*>();
      Q_ASSERT(sibling);
      label->setParent(sibling->parent());
      label->move(sibling->bottomLeft());
      label->setVisible(sibling->hasFocus());
    }
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *ev) override {
      if (auto *label = getLabel(obj))
        if (ev->type() == QEvent::Resize || ev->type() == QEvent::Move 
            || ev->type() == QEvent::ParentChange || ev->type() == QEvent::FocusIn
            || ev->type() == QEvent::FocusOut)
          updateLabel(label);
      return false;
    }
   public:
    using QObject::QObject;
  };
  auto *label = Filter::getLabel(widget);
  if (!label) {
    label = new QLabel(widget->parent());
    label->setProperty(kTrackedSibling, QVariant::fromValue(widget));
    widget->setProperty(kLabelSibling, QVariant::fromValue(label));
    widget->installEventFilter(new Filter(widget));
    QObject::connect(widget, &QObject::destroyed, label, [widget, label]{
      widget->setProperty(kLabelSibling, {});
      label->setProperty(kTrackedSibling, {});
      label->deleteLater();
    });
  }
  label->setText(text);
  Filter::updateLabel(label);
}
```

(Sorry, the above is untested and written from memory)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I have tried the same but instead of adding a event filter from out side.  I have subclassed QPushButton and I am changing the position of label in the changeEvent method for move, resize,parentChange , show and hide events. But the issue is whenever the view is shown for the first time sometimes the label is not shown or label position doesn't update properly. But apart from that it works fine. Do you have any idea about why is this happening?

Comment: Subclassing should be a last resort, because it couples your code tightly to a control. The event filter approach will work for any focusable control. Without showing the code, I can't tell you what you did wrong, sorry.